# Blender using my CPU instead of GPU even though all settings are set to GPU

Tags: rendering, gpu

I have a problem where no matter what I do Blender utilizes my CPU instead of my selected GPU.

I have a fairly older CPU and a much stronger newer GPU - RTX 2060, that's why I want to utilize it.

I tried everything but I can not find the solution.
I am using Blender 2.92
I enabled CUDA ( Also tried OptiX - did not work) in my preferences, checked the compatibility and selected my GPU.
Cycles is selected with GPU compute
I tried reinstalling blender several time with no change.
No matter what I change whenever I try to render a liquid simulation for example, my CPU usage is 100% and my GPU is 0%.

I have no idea what else to do.

EDIT 1:
Checked again in task manager specifically CUDA and not general GPU and it remains at 0%

EDIT 2:
Problem was, I'm just stupid and did not realise you exclusively use CPU for physics.

Comment: Hello :). Simulations are only calculated on CPU (and often single threaded). GPU is used for rendering and viewport.

Comment: I did not know that, I thought that if GPU is selected that it can run physics as well. Thank you for the help.

Comment: GPU render works fine in the end. All of the aforementioned things are adjusted right.

Comment: No problem :). This is specific to Blender. Other software (like Houdini) will happily run physics on a GPU :)

Answer (score 2):

It might be that you looking the performance of integrated gpu, that's why it shows 0%.
In task manager make sure you are looking the stats of your dedicated gpu.
Also change `graph` to `cuda`
[image]